# What files should I download?

Tags: r

```r
male <- filter(nym.2002, gender=="Male") %>% select(time) %>% unlist
# Error in select(., time) : unused argument (time)
```

Hi! Could you tell me what I did wrong?) Probably I have not downloaded some files...

Comment: (1) `%>% select(x) %>% unlist` --> `%>% pull(x)`. (2) Please make this question more reproducible by including representative sample data (e.g., `dput(head(num.2002))`) and the output from `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: This error often occurs because the `MASS` library is loaded and R uses the `select` command from that package. Try `dplyr::select` instead of `select` and see if that helps.